# Verbatim Literals in Managed C++? (like C#'s @"blah")

Tags: .net, c++, .net-2.0, string, managed-c++

Is there a way to use verbatim String literals in managed C++? Similar to C#'s

```
String Docs = @"c:\documents and settings\"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in C++11, there is raw string literal:

```
cout<<R"((\"ddd\aa)\n)"<<endl;
cout<<R"delimiter((\"ddd\aa)\n)delimiter"<<endl;
```

output is:

```
(\"ddd\aa)\n
(\"ddd\aa)\n
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not currently possible.  Managed C++ string literals have almost the exact same rules as normal C++ strings.  The managed C++ spec is in fact just an augmentation of the ANSI C++ standard.

Currently there is no support for C# style literal syntax in C++ (managed or not).  You must manually escape every character.

See Section 9.1.3.3 in the C++/CLI spec for more details. ([Spec Link)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-372.pdf)

Comment: This answer was much more correct when it was given then it is now.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett in light of reflection of current state of things should we edit or remove this post?

Comment: Raw string literals can be used to achieve the desired result: String^ f = gcnew String(R"(C:\foo\bar.txt)");    [Google msdn C++ String Literals for more info]

Answer (score 3):

While not quite as terse as the '@' C# verbatim string literal, the following does compile /Clr:pure, so  you can use C++ Raw String Literals for pure MSIL and a similar result:

```
String^ f = gcnew String(R"(C:\foo\bar.txt)");
```

Raw string literals can be used in regular C++ also:

```
char *x = R"(C:\foo\bar.txt)";
```

Google "msdn C++ String Literals" for more info

Comment: Oh!  great!!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

snip .. For .NET Programming, Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2017 supports the creation of mixed assemblies by using the /clr (Common Language Runtime Compilation) compiler option. The /clr:pure and clr:safe options are deprecated in Visual Studio 2015 and unsupported in Visual Studio 2017. If your code needs to be safe or verifiable, then we recommend that you port it to C#.